# On-premise SharePoint report integration to Power BI Reporting Server

Tags: sharepoint-2013, power-bi-report-server

Our company has a on-premise SharePoint site with reports of .rdl, Excel, Word, PDF. We also have a cloud-based Power BI Reporting Server. The SharePoint site is going away soon, and we are looking at the possibility to migrate the SP reports into PBI Reporting server. Is it possible? If yes, please elaborate the steps to proceed. Thank you.